# Question about rabbitmq message persistence mechanism

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I am reading [Persistence Configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html), and I have some questions.

I know that queues can be either durable or not, and messages are also divided into two categories: persistent or transient.

As the document says: Persistent messages will be written to disk as soon as they reach the queue.

So, here are my questions:

1. If I send a message and the message was not distributed to any queues,
   will the message be persistent?
2. If a queue is non-durable, will the message(persistent or transient, not
   being consumed) be deleted from disk when the queue is deleted?
3. If a message is consumed, does rabbitmq delete this messages from
   physical storage?

Any ideas on how to test these conditions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I send a message and the message was not distributed to any queues, will the message be persistent?

No, see `mandatory` to handle the unroutable messages.

> If a queue is non-durable, will the message(persistent or transient, not being consumed) be deleted from disk when the queue is deleted?

yes

> If a message is consumed, does rabbitmq delete this messages from physical storage?

When a message is consumed and the status is `unacked` the message is not removed.

when you send the `ack` or `nack` the message is removed from the memory/disk.